# Why there is no regex match in the output of this wget command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, wget, stderr

I download a file from internet with `wget` and I want to record the name of the actual downloaded file (it changes in case the file already exists).
I know that `wget` output goes to `stderr`, that is why I try to search for a regex match in it. There should be one but my "match" is `None` (because I get the error that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

```
cmd = "wget " + url + " -P " + directory
args = shlex.split(cmd)
res = subprocess.run(args, check=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
pattern = re.compile("\'(.+)\'", re.MULTILINE)
match = re.search(pattern, res.stderr.decode("utf-8"))
filename = match.group(1) # filename is None
```

But when I check the value of `stderr`, it looks like this:

```
... connected.HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OKLength: 
46Saving to: '/home/student/Downloads/helloworld'     0K
```

I have tried to pass the command as a string to `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`, the regex with `re.MULTILINE` and without, and other things, to no avail.

Comment: I tried your example and it works for me.

Comment: hum... on another machine, it works for me too. I can't explain...

Comment: when I try to match just an apostrophe with `pattern = re.compile("\'")`, it does not find a it.

Comment: You can `print(res.stderr.decode('utf-8'))` and see the single quote? Maybe its one of the other unicode quote chars. Try `for c in res.stderr.decode('utf-8'): print(c, ord(c))` and look to see whether that quote is really ordinal 39.

Comment: @ tdelaney thanks for helping. Indeed the single quoteS look different than the prime symbol. first quote ordinal value is 8216 and the second is 8217. What to do to fix this?

Comment: I don't know the rules for which type of quote to use. You could replace those values before the regex or include both the values in the regex `"(?:('|‘))(.+)(?:'|’)` or see if the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) does what you want and skip the wget problem completely.

Comment: my solution that fixed it: `re.compile("[‘’\'](.+)[‘’\']")`